# WAMP - Maximum execution time exceeded - Can no longer upload photos via Wordpress Media Upload

Tags: php, wordpress, wampserver

This is a recent issue that is causing a headache.

Each time I try to upload a photo via media upload, I am met with the upload bar reading 100%... a stall, and then an error stating:
`Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded`

The file could be tiny or big - it won't even upload a 10kb file.

My WP debug log states the following:

```
[05-Sep-2021 16:07:56 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp64\www\sns\wp-includes\functions.php on line 8051
[05-Sep-2021 16:07:56 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[05-Sep-2021 16:07:56 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp64\www\sns\wp-admin\async-upload.php:0
[05-Sep-2021 16:07:56 UTC] PHP   2. wp_ajax_upload_attachment() C:\wamp64\www\sns\wp-admin\async-upload.php:33
[05-Sep-2021 16:07:56 UTC] PHP   3. media_handle_upload() C:\wamp64\www\sns\wp-admin\includes\ajax-actions.php:2549
[05-Sep-2021 16:07:56 UTC] PHP   4. wp_handle_upload() C:\wamp64\www\sns\wp-admin\includes\media.php:303
[05-Sep-2021 16:07:56 UTC] PHP   5. _wp_handle_upload() C:\wamp64\www\sns\wp-admin\includes\file.php:1037
[05-Sep-2021 16:07:56 UTC] PHP   6. clean_dirsize_cache() C:\wamp64\www\sns\wp-admin\includes\file.php:981
```

What I have tried:

1. Restarting WAMP server.
2. Upgrading my PHP version.
3. Using a different theme.
4. Deactivating all plugins.

One thing that may be the cause (and the only other thing I can think of), is that I recently installed and setup Homestead & Vagrant in order to create an environment to start developing using Laravel.

Could this have anything to do with it? If so, where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change that configuration in the php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 1200
```

or,

```
left click on wampmanager icon -> PHP -> PHP Settings
```

and find max_execution_time configuration

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. The issue remains. It isn't a case of the file not being able to be processed in the maximum time - even a tiny file isn't being processed. Something is going wrong during upload.

I have also managed to determine that it isn't so much a server issue, as a different local wordpress install is uploading fine. This is crazy.

Comment: Can you provide step how to reproduce this case or screenshot? so we can looking more forward for this issues.

Comment: So I managed to figure it out - turns out it is a bug in the new updates that only affects multi-site setups on a local machine. I have posted the answer and solution to this question above, in the hopes it helps someone else. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this VERY unique issue...

The issue lied in the fact my site is a multi-site install. Apparently there is a cache bug that triggers this issue.

[Source: Where I found people with similar issue.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/iis-wordpress-5-6-multi-sites-file-upload-hang/)

Within that link someone had posted the following code, which can be installed as a plugin. Ultimately, it fixed my issue. Hope this helps someone until Wordpress fixes the bug.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Multisite Cache Bug 
 * Description: A potential fix for the problem mentioned at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/iis-wordpress-5-6-multi-sites-file-upload-hang/#post-13867460
 * Version: 0.1
 * License: GPL2
 */

// Prevent direct access to this file
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

add_filter( "transient_dirsize_cache", function() {return; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

That limit is part of the PHP.INI file.

WAMPServer has made that a bit easier to change, and can be done from the wampmanager menu in the system tray

[image]

Left click the wampmanager icon -> PHP -> PHP Settings ->
Max Execution Time

Then pick a larger number from the dropdown. Wait a few seconds and wampserver will restart Apache and the new Max Execution Time will be set